# Can we use a public key scheme for performing cryptographic commitment

Tags: encryption, cryptography, public-key-infrastructure

Is it possible to use a public key scheme such as DSA as a commitment scheme? Are there any problems with doing this?

Comment: I'm not particularly knowledgeable about commitment schemes, but is there a reason you wouldn't use a standard block cipher for this? Encrypt the data, distribute the ciphertext, then release the key later.

Comment: I am new to this as well. I'd like to know if there are any security characteristics specific to commitment schemes which are not available through block ciphers / public key schemes?

Comment: I'll poke Thomas Pornin (our resident cryptographer) about this when I see him.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer can be yes or no depending on what you mean by commitment.

In a [commitment scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commitment_scheme), you have a piece of data (*d*) from which you compute a value *c* which you publish; at a later date, you publish *d*. This is a commitment if the following is true:

- From *c*, one cannot recompute *d*.
- Everybody knowing *c* and *d* must be able to ascertain that they match.
- It must not be possible, even for you, to find a *d'* distinct from *d* but which still matches *c*.

On the surface, this looks a lot like a [cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), with some subtle details. If you compute *c* as *h(d)* for a hash function *h* (say SHA-256), then you fulfill the commitment properties, *except* that the commitment is vulnerable to exhaustive search on the data *d*. One could try potential data elements *d*, and hash them all, to see if one matches *c*. That's a problem also encountered with storing password hashes. The solution is **randomization**: you compute *c* as *h(r||d)* where *r* is some random padding (say 16 random bytes). When you open the commitment, you publish both *r* and *d*. The randomness of *r* protects against exhaustive search.

What would a signature scheme like DSA do in that picture? Not much, really. Instead of hashing, you could *sign*, but since everybody can *verify* the signature, you still would have the exhaustive search issue (DSA includes some random data, but not in the "right place" for a commitment scheme). Indeed, DSA begins by hashing the data, so you are really using a hash function, and the DSA around it is a needless complication.

**Some commitment schemes** provide more than just the ability to commit to an arbitrary value; they also allow to prove *without opening the commitment* that the committed-to value fulfills some algebraic properties. This is used, for instance, in some electronic voting protocols (the vote is encrypted, but the voter can show that the vote is either a 0 or a 1, *not* another integer). This kind of commitment requires mathematics besides just a hash: it may reuse some elements which are also used in some asymmetric encryption and signature algorithms (like operations modulo a big prime), but not just the asymmetric encryption or signature algorithms alone.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain a commitment from a public-key encryption scheme by having Alice obtain $(PK,SK) = Gen(1^n,r_g)$ (where $r_g$ is the random coins for the $Gen$ algorithm). To commit to the message $m$ she sends $PK$ and $c=E_{PK}(m;r_e)$ to Bob, where $r_e$ is the random coins used in the encryption. To open the commitment in a later point in time Alice sends $m,r_g$ to bob, who in turn obtains $(PK,SK) = Gen(1^n,r_g)$ and verifies that $c=E_{PK}(m;r)$.

Just sending $c$ and $PK$ in the commit phase and later send $SK$ and $m$ in the opening does not guarantees *binding* since there might be other $SK'$ and $m'$ such that $m'=D_{SK}(m)$. The same holds for sending $r_e$ in the opening phase.

For more details [see this](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/courses/spring12/CSCI-GA.3210-001/lect/lecture14.pdf).